# Second order non-linear PDE solution in closed form or general solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes

I have the following partial differential equation, that i am trying to solve,

$$0=A_{t}-A(t,r_{t})\alpha+A_{r}\beta r(t)+A_{rr}\sigma_{r}-c\frac{A_{r}^{2}}{A(t,r_{t})}$$

where $\alpha, \beta$ and c are constants and $A_r$ and $A_t$ are the partial derivatives with respect to $r$ and $t$ respectively, and A(t,r) is the unknown function whose boundary condition is given by,

$A(T,r_T)=1$,

I know that if I don't have the last term in the above equation, I can find the solution using the Feynman kac formula. Any hint or direction will be much appreciated.

Thank you,